# Google form collects two dates with different timezones

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, datepicker, google-forms

I have two datepickers in the same google form. When I try to format these dates using Google App Scripts I run into an issue where both dates have a different timezone.

Code:

```
  Logger.log('Original value: '+data[0][column]+' - Data for document: '+Utilities.formatDate(data[0][column], "GMT+1", "dd-MM-yyyy"));
```

Result:

```
[18-03-27 10:06:25:299 CEST] Original value: Sun Apr 01 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (CEST) - Data for document: 31-03-2018
[18-03-27 10:06:25:304 CEST] Original value: Mon Mar 12 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET) - Data for document: 12-03-2018
```

I don't really need to convert these dates to a specific timezone, just converting it to the right format would be sufficient. So this case shows 31-03-2018 as a result of my formatting while it should be 01-04-2018. For the other datepicker it works fine. Any ideas?

To clarify: both dates are entered in a single form submission. It's an absolute mystery for me why these dates would have different timezones.

Comment: The reason those datetimes have different timezones is because DST goes into effect between those two dates.

Answer (score 0):

One option to test would be to make sure you were always feeding the date format Utility the same timezone objects.

```
var d = new Date(data[0][column]);
var utc = new Date(d.toUTCString());

Utilities.formatDate(utc, "GMT+1", "dd-MM-yyyy"))
```

This is somewhat overkill and shorterhand methods would have the same result.

FWIW I don't like the Utility date functions in GAS

Comment: Tried this but has exactly the same result unfortunately.

Comment: @Casper then always only use UTC and stop worrying about timezones. :)

Comment: @tehhowch fair point. Set the timezone to GMT+4 to prevent the date being converted to the day before.

Comment: @Casper that's hackish. Use `Date#getTime()`, since it always returns milliseconds since epoch in UTC.

Comment: @tehhowch in principal that’s what I’d suggest too. It can be difficult to debug seconds from epoch however ;)